# NgWebDriver working only after reloading the page . Why?

Tags: java, angular, selenium

I am using selenium and NgWebDriver for angular testing angular app. When I use ngWebDriver, It is taking long time for the testing but once I refresh the page It is working smoothly and all the tests pass withing short period of time.
Why I need to refresh  the page ?
Or What can be done to avoid refreshing the page ?
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use driver.navigate().refresh() after your page loads